# Trying to create jar from Axis2 generated code

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-axis

I have generated axis2 code, and I would like to use the build.xml to create a jar file.

When I try and run the build.xml I get the following error

```
Buildfile: /home/user/workspace/Axis2WSTest/build.xml
init:
pre.compile.test:

BUILD FAILED
/home/user/workspace/Axis2WSTest/build.xml:31: /home/user/workspace/Axis2WSTest/${env.AXIS2_HOME} does not exist.
```

I have tried doing

```
export AXIS2_HOME=/home/user/Desktop/Axis2-1.0
```

It binds the var correct but still getting the same error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show the contents of your `build.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the setenv.sh in /bin folder of your axis2 folder

Comment: I run bin/setenv.sh
 
 Using AXIS2_HOME: ./
 Using JAVA_HOME:  /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk

Same problem still

Comment: Do you use the same profile when you set variable and launch command?

Comment: Running bin/setenv.sh as both root and as my normal user. Does eclipse need a different account?

Comment: /home/user/workspace/Axis2WSTest/${env.AXIS2_HOME} -> /home/user/workspace/Axis2WSTest/home/user/Desktop/Axis2-1.0

Comment: I'm not sure what that means?

Comment: maybe it try to reach this folder: /home/user/workspace/Axis2WSTest/home/user/Desktop/Axis2-1.0 and not /home/user/Desktop/Axis2-1.0

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set your AXIS2_HOME variable, you can do like this:

```
AXIS2_HOME=path_to_axis_bin_folder ant jar.server
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. I closed eclipse, set the AXIS2_HOME environment variable, reopened eclipse, and I was able to successfully build. The instructions for setting this up is on the Apache Axis2 Installation Guide here: http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/installationguide.html#standalone1

In case the link goes dead:

> Download and unpack the Axis2 Standard Binary Distribution into a convenient location so that the distribution resides in its own directory. Set an environment variable AXIS2_HOME to the pathname of the extracted directory of Axis2 (Eg: /opt/axis2-1.6.2). Linux users can alternatively run the setenv.sh file available in the AXIS2_HOME/bin directory to set the AXIS2_HOME environment variable to the Axis2 classpath.